# What is the year of my Mercedes C220 car? [UK]

Tags: mercedes-benz

My car has a 51 plate, but when I put my number plate in the http://www.eurocarparts.com/ site; my car is getting identified as:

```
Mercedes-Benz ( 2002) 
C Class 2.1
```

Doesn't 51 plate means year 2001 in the UK?

Comment: You could always type your registration into comparethemarket.com and this will also tell you the age of the car. I often did it when looking up what cars were from pictures on eBay and things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. The number sequence is split from 1 March to 31 August, then from 1 September through the end of February. In your case, the 51 plate is saying your car is a 2002 as 51 falls under the latter case. This, I believe, has to do with model year and when it was manufactured.

Here is a breakdown in how the years suss out (taken from [this website](http://www.theaa.com/motoring_advice/car-buyers-guide/cbg_numberplates.html)):

```
Year        1 March to      1 September to
            end August      end February

2001/02                         51
2002/03         02              52
2003/04         03              53
2004/05         04              54
2005/06         05              55
2006/07         06              56
2007/08         07              57
2008/09         08              58
2009/10         09              59
2010/11         10              60
2011/12         11              61
2012/13         12              62
2013/14         13              63
2014/15         14              64
2015/16         15              65
2016/17         16              66
2017/18         17              67
2018/19         18              68
2019/20         19              69
2020/21         20              70
2021/22         21              71
2022/23         and so on   until 50/00
                            in 2050/51
```